# sn_complie.sh error: Failed to create Specman's temporary directory `/local/temp/specman'

Tags: specman, e

I'm trying to complie an e file using sn_compile.sh script. I get an error:

```
Failed to create Specman's temporary directory
     `/local/temp/specman'
```

even though I defined explicitly temp files directory. The command I run:

```
sn_complile.sh efile.e -t temp/
```

How can I solve the error? 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`TMDDIR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR) environment variable before calling `sn_compile.sh`